# Show $a_n$ is monotone

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

let $a_n$ such that $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} = 3 - {1 \over a_{n}}$.

Well, We're asking if $a_{n+1} > a_n$, then $3-{1\over a_n} > a_n$.
Hence, $a_n^2 - 3a_n +1 < 0$

We got a quadratic equation. What does it tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove by induction that $a_n > a_{n-1} > 0$.

**Hint:** $a_{n+1} > a_n \Leftrightarrow 3 - \frac{1}{a_n} > 3 - \frac{1}{a_{n-1} } \Leftrightarrow a_{n} > a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it means that, whatever $n$ could be $a(n)$ will be between the two roots of the quadratic equation; these roots are $\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)$.

Just try with the first terms; you will successively get $1$, $2$, $5/2$, $13/5$, $34/13$, $89/34$ and so on. $a(n)$ will goes asymptotically to $\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)$ which is $2.61803$.

Comment: but how does the fact that: "will be between the two roots of the quadratic equation" implies that $a_{n+1} > a_n$?

Comment: I guess that just because the terms increase and go to the asymptote.